# Powershell script to export email address of users in an OU

Tags: active-directory, powershell, scripting

so I have a ton of OU's on our DC that are all formatted the same way with a 6 digit number to start and then a name after the number. I am wondering if there is a way to write a Powershell script where I fill out a csv file with the 6 digit number and then to have it display the email address of all the users in that OU.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that ServerFault is not a free script writing service.  We request and require that all questions include research effort and/or examples of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following (you need to adjust the OrganizationalUnit part, so that it fits your environment):

```
CLS
Write-Host "Please wait ... working ..."

$Users = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "DC=int,DC=contoso,DC=com" -ResultSize unlimited

$OutPutFile1="C:\temp\ExportFile_pipe_separated.csv"

#Build header from export:
$OutputHeaderString = "UserAlias|UserDisplayName|UserItemCount|UserTotalItemSize (in MB)|UserLastLogonTime|Database|ServerName|OrganizationalUnit|ActiveSyncStatus|PrimarySmtpAddress"
$OutputHeaderString | Out-File $OutPutFile1 -Append
Write-Host "UserAlias|UserDisplayName|UserItemCount|UserTotalItemSize (in MB)|UserLastLogonTime|Database|ServerName|OrganizationalUnit|ActiveSyncStatus|PrimarySmtpAddress"

# Do the following for each user
foreach ($User in $Users)
{

    # Get the user's alias and display name
    $UserAlias = $User.Alias
    $UserDisplayName = $User.DisplayName
    $UsersMailDB = $User.Database
    $UsersServerName = $User.ServerName


    # Get the user's mailbox statistics on ItemCount
    $UserItemCount = Get-MailboxStatistics $UserDisplayName | Select-Object ItemCount
    $UserItemCount = $UserItemCount.ItemCount
    $UserOrgUnit = $User.OrganizationalUnit

    # Get the users active sync status
    $UserActiveSyncStatusTEMP = Get-CASMailbox -Identity $UserDisplayName | Select-Object ActiveSyncEnabled
    $UserActiveSyncStatus = $UserActiveSyncStatusTEMP.ActiveSyncEnabled

    # Get PrimarySmtpAddress
    $UserPrimarySmtpAddress = $User.PrimarySmtpAddress

    # Get the user's mailbox statistics on TotalItemSize, format to just MB / GB
    $UserTotalItemSize = Get-MailboxStatistics $UserDisplayName | Select-Object TotalItemSize
    $UserTotalItemSize = $UserTotalItemSize.TotalItemSize.Value.toMB()
    #$UserTotalItemSize = $UserTotalItemSize.TotalItemSize.Value.toGB()

    # Get the user's mailbox statistics on LastLogonTime
    $UserLastLogonTime = Get-MailboxStatistics $UserDisplayName | Select-Object LastLogonTime
    $UserLastLogonTime = $UserLastLogonTime.LastLogonTime

        # Combine results into a pipe-delimited string
        $OutputString = $UserAlias + "|" + $UserDisplayName + "|" + $UserItemCount + "|" + $UserTotalItemSize + "|" + $UserLastLogonTime + "|" + $UsersMailDB + "|" + $UsersServerName + "|" + $UserOrgUnit + "|" + $UserActiveSyncStatus + "|" + $UserPrimarySmtpAddress

        # Write the results to a .csv file
        $OutputString | Out-File $OutPutFile1 -Append

        # Display the results on the screen to show progress
        Write-Host $OutputString

}
```

You can then save the content to a *.ps1 and run it, so that generates an *.csv file which you can then import in excel and do some transforming.

*Its based on an original code from [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/303-export-exchange-user-who-didn%C2%B4t-logged-in-since-some-days-as-csv.html)*

Answer (score 0):

If the number is unique this will work, but doesn't completely meet your requirements of the csv input.  I'll leave that for your research part as I agree with @Colyn1337.

```
$TheInput = Read-Host -Prompt "What are we looking for today?"
$OU = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {Name -like $TheInput} -SearchScope Subtree
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $OU | Select-Object Name, mail
```